# jmeter testplan with encoded path not working

Tags: jmeter

In my jmeter testplan.jmx I have changed the path to something like below [encoded and just pasted the output to .jmx file]
"%2Fpublic%2Fwebapp%2FmetricsData%2F3%2FrangeByName%3Ffacet%3DHOST%226facet%3DHOST%26starttime%3D1395138030000%26endtime%3D1395310830000"

When I try to run the jmeter test in unix, im getting error as,

jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSampler: Error Response Code: 404

Can someone help me on this issue

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked for any space that might get added while copying and pasting??

Comment: sorry for late reply, I checked for any spaces, but still it is not working out